# Chrome input autofill issue

Tags: css, reactjs, google-chrome

Sorry if this is a duplicate but I couldn't find an answer. I'm currently trying to both disable autoComplete and remove the default styling from chrome on :active, etc. I've tried various examples but come up with nothing.

```
<input
   type="email"
   name="email"
   className={style['form-control']}
   id="exampleInputEmail1"
   aria-describedby="emailHelp"
   required
   onComplete="off"
   onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e)}
></input>
```

```
.form-control {
   background-color: $bg3 !important;
   width: 100% !important;
   color: #D7E5F0 !important;
   font-size: 14px !important;
   padding: 7px 15px !important;
   border: none !important;
}
```

chrome:
https://gyazo.com/cb8354cecb39fc9d8f479b4d5ecca3f7

Comment: The attribute should be `autocomplete="off"` not `onComplete="off"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix for now with the following code:

```
.form-control,
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus, 
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
    background-color: $bg3 !important;
    color: #D7E5F0 !important;
    outline: none;
    border: none !important;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #D7E5F0 !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px $bg3 inset !important;
}
```